# why A type is missing in function definition?

Tags: scala

Why is the declaration of aggregate function without A in square brackets while A is being used in `seqop`?

```
def aggregate[B](z: B)(seqop: (B, A) ⇒ B, combop: (B, B) ⇒ B): B
```

instead of

```
def aggregate[A,B](z: B)(seqop: (B, A) ⇒ B, combop: (B, B) ⇒ B): B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about Scala collections. `aggregate` is the method of the trait `GenTraversableOnce` which is already parameterized by the type parameter `A`:

```
trait GenTraversableOnce[+A] {
    ...
    abstract def aggregate[B](z: ⇒ B)(seqop: (B, A) ⇒ B, combop: (B, B) ⇒ B): B
}
```

So, you don't need to declare another type parameter `A` because it is already defined! Moreover, if you declare a new type parameter `A`, it will shadow the existing `A` which will result in not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to [`TraversableOnce#aggregate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html), it's because `A` is a type parameter of the `TraversableOnce` trait.

The code looks something like this:

```
trait TraversableOnce[+A] extends Any with GenTraversableOnce[A] {

  def aggregate[B](z: =>B)(seqop: (B, A) => B, combop: (B, B) => B): B =
    foldLeft(z)(seqop)

  // ... and many other things ...

}
```

The `A` parameter is bound by the trait, and the `B` parameter is bound by the method.